# Two rotated squares with TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create figures of this kind
[image]

Moreover, I would prefer to create a command with 9 arguments that specify whether each circle is colored in respective color or left white.

As an initial approximation, I thought of using the TIKZ graphs library for this purpose.

I copied this example from the manual:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,onecolumn,openright,final,oneside]{memoir}
%===============================================
\settrims{0.cm}{0.cm}
\setbinding{0cm} % space for binding
\setlrmarginsandblock{*}{3cm}{1} % spine = edge. Edge=3cm
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1} % upper=lower. Upper=3cm
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\begin{document}
\tikz
  \graph [nodes={draw, circle}, clockwise, radius=.75cm, empty nodes, n=8] {
    subgraph C_n [name=inner] <->[shorten <=1pt, shorten >=1pt]
    subgraph C_n [name=outer]
  };
\end{document}
```

I compiled this file with xelatex and this is what I got
[image]

I was expecting something like this

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not sure if I would use graph drawing for this. You seem to know very well how the result should look like, i.e. I do not see the need for a layout algorithm. A very simpleminded macro of the type you suggest is the following. (Fixed colors, modulos can be tricky. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathparse{\mycolors[1]}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,minimum size=3cm,\pgfmathresult](square1){};
\pgfmathparse{\mycolors[0]}
\node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=4,draw,minimum size=3cm,rotate=45,\pgfmathresult]
(square0){};
\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(mod(\Y+1,2))},
evaluate=\Y as \V using {int((\Y+1)/2)}] in {#1}
{\ifnum\Y=9
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\mycolors[2]}
 \ifnum\X=1
  \filldraw[\mycolor] (0,0) circle (3mm);
 \else
  \draw[thick,fill=white,draw=\mycolor] (0,0) circle (3mm);
 \fi
\else
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\mycolors[\Z]}
 \ifnum\X=1
  \filldraw[\mycolor] (square\Z.corner \V) circle (3mm);
 \else
  \draw[thick,fill=white,draw=\mycolor] (square\Z.corner \V) circle (3mm);
 \fi
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\xdef\mycolors{{"black","red","cyan"}}
\mymacro{1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `0` and `1` entries determine if a given circle is filled, the 9th entry is the dot in the middle. The colors are stored in the `\mycolors` array.

Comment: This is an incredible answer: fast and precise!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to draw.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
\def\a{2}
\def\r{.5}
\fill[cyan] (0,0) circle(\r);

\begin{scope}[rotate=-135]
\draw[gray] (-\a,-\a) rectangle (\a,\a);
\filldraw (\a,-\a) circle(\r);
\filldraw (-\a,\a) circle(\r);
\filldraw (-\a,-\a) circle(\r);
\filldraw (\a,\a) circle(\r);
\end{scope}

\draw[red] (-\a,-\a) rectangle (\a,\a);
\filldraw[red] (\a,-\a) circle(\r);
\filldraw[red] (\a,\a) circle(\r);
\filldraw[red] (-\a,-\a) circle(\r);
\draw[red,fill=white] (-\a,\a) circle(\r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]